# а если вы нажмёте на синюю(,) – собака получит сельдерея корень

Tags: запятые

Нужна та запятая?

• Если вы нажмёте на красную кнопку, то кот получит морковь, а если вы нажмёте на синюю **(,)** – собака получит сельдерея корень.

Comment: Кот "получит" морковь, если её возьмет. По-русски не говорят про будущее "получит". Если это не фраза вроде - он у меня еще получит. Коту дадут морковь/ морковь упадет в кошачью миску. Хотя можно: кот получит удар током, - но! потому что кота ударит током; получит - не самодостаточный глагол в данном случае. И с местоимениями его можно употреблять: он получит морковь. Либо так: если вы нажмёте кнопку, то кот - получит морковь(так как пропущено "он"). Или полное может звучать как: если нажмёте кнопку, то кот сможет съесть морковь - он её получит.

Comment: А можно так сказать: Если судьи дадут хорошую оценку за  это упражнение, то спортсмен получит золотую медаль.

Comment: Можно, но спортсмен - это понятие и суть латинизм, а кот - нет, кот - это существительное. Смешение грамматики языков какое-то, слова русские, а грамматика латыни. А вот "...то борец получит золотую медаль" - тут уже проблемы возникают, так как - какой борец? но борец вроде все же спортсмен и возможно к названиям людей это работает, а вот кот - это не называние кота. Можно сказать: правый кот получит морковь, - потому что "правый получит морковь". То есть или определить кота нужно, или поставить в косвенный падеж - коту дадут морковь, а "кот получит" - это очень странно.

Comment: Спортсмен - тот, кто занимается спортом. Может быть качеством и предикацией некой. А кот, это не тот, кто "кот", или тот который кто?.

Comment: Не знаю. У меня есть кот. И он получит мясо, если будет хорошо себя вести. Словарь: ПОЛУЧИТЬ. 5. что. // Быть вознаграждённым чем-л. П. благодарность, приз, похвальный лист, грамоту. П. первую премию. П. орден, медаль.

Comment: А грамматика у нас греческого образца, так Пушкин считал. Как он говорил, греческий язык даровал славянскому «законы обдуманной своей грамматики, свои прекрасные обороты, величественное течение речи; словом, усыновил его, избавя таким образом от медленных усовершенствований времени» . https://rvb.ru/pushkin/01text/07criticism/01criticism/0124_30/0914.htm

Comment: Он получит! А не кот получит. Кот получит мясо, как будто кота зовут Кот. У меня есть кот, его зовут Кот, Кот получит мясо, если будет вести себя хорошо. Из слова кот нельзя даже приближенно сделать глагол или признак "кота". Кошка - вероятно, кошка получит мясо, но кот - нет. Насчет "от греческого" - может быть.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Если** вы нажмёте на красную кнопку, **то** кот получит морковь, **а если** вы нажмёте на синюю – собака получит сельдерея корень.*

1. Я думаю, что запятая не нужна. Тире **замещает** запятую при отсутствии местоимения "то"  в двойном союзе "если...то". Именно замещает, а не дополняет, это интонационное/факультативное тире. Можно вместо тире поставить запятую, но тогда увеличенная пауза не будет обозначена.
2. **Но вопрос сложный**. Дело в том, что использование **двойного союза** "если...то" тоже факультативно, по этой теме нет четких правил. Практика письма говорит о том, что двойной союз нужен в сложных предложениях для обозначения ясности структуры. И вот местоимение "то" удобно заменить тире, так как оно выполняет ту же функцию (делает грамматику более понятной).

Но кто-то может настаивать на сохранении запятой (тире дополняет запятую), хотя никакой **полезной** нагрузки в сочетании знаков нет.

3. Тире вместо запятой – это обычная практика письма, отдельная тема **[в правилах Розенталя](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=142#pp142).**  Тире рекомендуется ставить в различных СПП, в том числе для отделения главной части от придаточной, в распространенных предложениях, при значении условия и т.д.

Поэтому можно сказать, что тире ставится в СПП с союзом "если" для обозначения увеличенной паузы **при пропуске** сущ. "кнопку". Это уже тема **неполных** предложений.

Но постановка тире в неполных предложениях тоже не является обязательной. Поэтому в конечном итоге все сводится к тому, что определенные знаки препинания нужны д**ля лучшего понимания** текста, и в каждом конкретном предложении делается свой выбор. Можно использовать местоимение "то", и тогда тире не надо ставить. И т.д.